# Creating view with nested 'no-lock' on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, business-intelligence, sql-view

Here is the scenario: I have some database model with about 500K new records everyday. The database is almost never updated (only insert statement and delete).

Many users would like to perform queries against database with tools such as PowerBI or so, but I haven't given any access to anybody to prevent deadlocking (I only allow specific IT managed resource to access the data).

I would like to open up data access, but I must prevent any one from blocking the new records insertions.

Could I create a view with nested no-lock inside it assuming no dirty read are created since no update are performed?

Would that be an acceptable design? I know it's is not a perfect solution and it's not mean for that.

It's a compromise to allow user with no SQL skills to perform ad-hoc queries and lookup.

Anything I might be missing?

Comment: This is quite broad and spanning several topics.

Comment: You could also look into optimistic locking models if you aren't prone to queries generating dirty reads.

Comment: you can't assume "no dirty read are created since no update are performed?"  an insert or delete could cause a page split which could lead to a dirty read

Comment: @user1443098 you are correct. I'm just throwing the idea out as perhaps another potential avenue. Certainly anyone should be hesitant to go that direction without significant testing and understanding the potential ramifications.

Comment: RCSI may be the ticket

Comment: Since you are not doing updates how are locks for inserts blocking? You can do selects with nolock but selects do not block writes. If you use optimistic locking it is true writers don't block readers and vice versa but its a lot of work on the instance to create your own, consistent, view of the data and it sounds like you want to avoid that.

Comment: `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`, an exclusive lock on the DB for the duration of the insert, a secondary server with the same data inserted (which can be tuned specifically to support the reporting queries), an availability group with a readable secondary, periodic backup/restores in another DB -- any of these are typically better choices than sprinkling `NOLOCK` around. The latter can still work, but only for queries where you don't really have to care if the results are wrong (for example, (semi) real time monitoring queries that will be refreshed quickly).

Comment: What do you mean by 'RCSI may be the ticket'? You do mean RCSI --> Read Commited Snapshot Isolation, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use 'WITH (NoLock) ' in front of table name in query, such as :

```
SELECT * FROM [table Name] WITH (NoLock)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, yet this is ideal for READPAST...
It will jump over locked row. no updates no locks for existing rows. If your assumption is wrong you'll get mistake results